# Render a variable from input JSON into Step Function non-path supported variable

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, amazon-forecast

I am trying to make the following spec work for setting up a Dataset Import. I am passing in an input JSON as shown below. The keys with `.$` JSONPath support are able to read the values from the input JSON.

However, I am unable to pass in a value from the input JSON into S3 object which does not seem to support the `Path.$`, and `Path` itself does not render the JSONPath structure.

How do I populate `Path` within the `S3Config` to read from the input JSON?

```
"Import-Forecast-Dataset": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "DatasetImportJobName.$": "$.ProjectName",
        "DatasetArn.$": "$.createDatasetResult.DatasetArn",
        "DataSource": {
          "S3Config": {
            "Path": "$.S3Path",
            "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
          }
        },
        "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:forecast:createDatasetImportJob",
      "Next": "Create-DatasetGroup",
      "ResultPath": "$.createDatasetImportJobResult"
    }
```

---

input JSON:

```
{
"ProjectName": "A",
"S3Path": "s3://somepath"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the `.$` suffix to the `Path` attribute.

```json
"Path.$": "$.S3Path",
```

If this is not the `StartAt` step within your state machine, it's possible that the input to the step is not including the `S3Path`. If this is the case, you can use the context object to get the input parameters to the function instead.

```json
"Path.$": "$$.Execution.Input.database",
```

---

I can verify creating a single step step function with the following, once executed does in fact pass the formed parameters correctly to the resource:

```json
{
  "End": true,
  "Parameters": {
    "DataSource": {
      "S3Config": {
        "Path.$": "$$.Execution.Input.S3Path",
        "RoleArn": "arn:xxx:iam::000000000000:role/xxxx"
      }
    },
    "DatasetArn.$": "$$.Execution.Input.DatasetArn",
    "DatasetImportJobName.$": "$$.Execution.Input.ProjectName",
    "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd"
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:forecast:createDatasetImportJob",
  "Type": "Task"
}
```

I then executed this with the following input:

```json
{
  "ProjectName":"XXXX",
  "DatasetArn":"arn:xxx:forecast:::test",
  "S3Path":"s3://dummy/prefix"
}
```

And verified in the execution console that this was the input passed to the step:

```json
{
  "DataSource": {
    "S3Config": {
      "RoleArn": "arn:xxx:iam::000000000000:role/xxxx",
      "Path": "s3://dummy/prefix"
    }
  },
  "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
  "DatasetArn": "arn:xxx:forecast:::test",
  "DatasetImportJobName": "XXXX"
}
```

Comment: I already tried using the `Path.$` and it said it was not supported for that function/processor.